# Selenium: UnhandledAlertException was unhandled

Tags: c#, selenium, unhandled-exception

I have been running automation testing on selenium (C#) for quite some time now, and I recently upgraded to version 2.37 with Chrome Driver 2.4. After this upgrade, for some reason every time an open dialog causes a test to fail, the exception is unhandled, which causes Visual Studio to completely freeze up and the rest of the test suite does not get executed.

Is there a good way to prevent this from occurring other than trying to avoid an alert from causing a test to fail? It is nice to test for that, so I do not want to simply dodge the issue. After a failing test, I attempt to switch to DefaultContent, and that is specifically where the "UnhandledAlertException was unhandled" gets thrown:

```
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
```

It is in a try-catch block, but this exception does not get caught for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();` is for switching frames. Quote from API:

> Selects either the first frame on the page or the main document when a
>   page contains iFrames.

You might want to try `IAlert` in WebDriver.dll.

For example

```
try {
   // doing your thing
} catch (UnhandledAlertException) {
    IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
    Console.WriteLine(alert.Text);
    alert.Accept(); // or alert.Dismiss(); depends on your needs
}
```